Bazel how to expose package root as environment variable a.k.a CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR
I am dealing with a corner case where CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR differs from PWD;
Apparently, that happens because the rules_rust for Bazel set the CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR via PWD and, somehow, this is different from what Cargo would set. The problem is that the Diesel migration macro requuires CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR, but because it's incorrectly set, the migration macro panics due to file not found when build with Bazel.
Under Cargo, CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR is set correctly and the same crate builds.
I cannot fully explain the details this strange issue when PWD and CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR aren't in sync, but it is a rare yet known corner case that has been discussed before.
In response, I have to overwrite the CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR in Bazel.
Here is the strange thing, the following genrule works on my Macbook, but fails with file not found on my CI that runs on Ubuntu Linux:
genrule(
name = "gen_env_file",
srcs = [
    "Cargo.toml"
],
outs = ["env_file.txt"],
cmd =  """(
    # Get the absolute path
    input_path=$$(realpath queng_infra/postgres/pg_smdb/Cargo.toml)

    # Remove /Cargo.toml from the path
    result_path="$${input_path%/Cargo.toml}"

    # Output the modified path
    echo "CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR=$$result_path"
 ) | tee $@""",
executable = True,
)

Apparently, realpath is not always able to get the correct path otherwise it would work on linux.
However, what seems to be working on all systems and all environment is location :target:
copy_directory(
 name = "copy_migrations",
 src = "migrations",
 out = "migrations",
)

rust_library(
name = "pg_smdb",
srcs = glob([
    "src/**",
]),
compile_data = [
    ":copy_migrations",
],
crate_root = "src/lib.rs",
    rustc_env = {
     "MIGRATION_DATA": "$(location :copy_migrations)",
    },
visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
deps = [],
)

The migrations folder is located under the package / crate root folder and "$(location :copy_migrations)" always returns the correct location in the file system.
However, the problem is, I actually need the location of the crate root folder itself, just one level above migrations to make stuff work.
And that is what I cannot figure out: How exactly do I locate the package root of the current package and expose it as an environment variable?
